# Create hash with keys from array and a standard value

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

What is the simplest way to turn it into:

```
{'a' => true, 'b' => true, 'c' => true}
```

`true` is just a standard value that values should hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Hash[ary.map {|k| [k, true]}]
```

Since Ruby 2.0 you can use `to_h` method:

```
ary.map {|k| [k, true]}.to_h
```

Answer (score 7):

How about below ?

```
2.1.0 :001 > ['a', 'b', 'c'].each_with_object(true).to_h
 => {"a"=>true, "b"=>true, "c"=>true}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your specific needs, maybe you do not actually need to initialize the values. You could simply create a Hash with a default value of `true` this way:

```
h = Hash.new(true)
#=> {}
```

Then, when you try to access a key that was not present before:

```
h['a']
#=> true

h['b']
#=> true
```

Pros: less memory used, faster to initialize.

Cons: does not actually store keys so the hash will be empty until some other code stores values in it. This will only be a problem if your program relies on reading the keys from the hash or wants to iterate over the hash.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
['a', 'b', 'c'].each_with_object({}) { |key, hash| hash[key] = true }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one

```
> Hash[arr.zip Array.new(arr.size, true)]
# => {"a"=>true, "b"=>true, "c"=>true}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Array#product](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].product([true]).to_h
  #=> {"a"=>true, "b"=>true, "c"=>true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will do this:

```
hash = {}
['a', 'b', 'c'].each{|i| hash[i] = true}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to Python, it's this easy:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(l, True)
>>> d
{'a': True, 'c': True, 'b': True}
```